# write from a specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

In my piece of code, I have,

```
 out.write(datGroup)
 out.write(' '*20+": Space Group\n")
 out.write(datLatx +"  ") 
 out.write(datLaty +"  ") 
 out.write(datLatz +"  ") 
 out.write('/'),     
 out.write(' '*20+": a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma\n")
```

which gives the output as:

```
189                    : Space Group
10  11  12  /                    : a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma
```

which is correct for what I have done, but not what I have want.

I want the ": Spacegroup" and ": a,b,c.." to start from the same column, irresepective of where the data of its row ended, like:

```
189                    : Space Group
10  11  12  /          : a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma
```

Can I do that in python3?

**EDIT after jonrsharpe's example**
So I have tried:

```
  def write_row(out, data, header, col=20):
    out.write("{0}: {1}".format(" ".join(map(str, data)).ljust(col), header))

  def print_data(self, BSub):
  .....
   with open("Init", mode='w') as out:
     write_row(out, (datGroup,), "Space Group")
```

which is giving error:

```
$ python3 geninit.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geninit.py", line 109, in print_data
    write_row(out, (datGroup,), "Space Group")
NameError: global name 'write_row' is not defined
```

Comment: Use string formatting with `'{}'.format`

Comment: @sshashank124: can you kindly give an little example?

Comment: @jonrsharpe has given a brilliant example. It is precisely what I was taking about. You should check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function to do this, for example:

```
def print_row(data, header, col=20):
    print("{0}: {1}".format(" ".join(map(str, data)).ljust(col), header))
```

Then call it for each case:

```
print_row((datGroup,), "Space Group")
print_row((datLatx, datLaty, datLatz), "a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma")
```

This gives, for example

```
>>> datGroup = 189
>>> datLatx, datLaty, datLatz = 11, 12, 13
>>> print_row((datGroup,), "Space Group")
189                 : Space Group
>>> print_row((datLatx, datLaty, datLatz, "/"), "a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma")
11 12 13 /          : a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma
```

This uses:

- `map(str, ...)` to convert all of the `data` into strings;
- `" ".join(...)` to put spaces between the `data` items;
- `str.ljust` to pad the left "column" with spaces, keeping it the same width; and
- `str.format` to put the padded left column and the header around the `": "`.

You can then adapt this to write to your output file (which you could pass as an argument) rather than `print` the data, e.g.:

```
def write_row(out, data, header, col=20):
    out.write(...)
```

and call

```
write_row(out, (datGroup,), "Space Group")
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed example, but as for a newbie, can you kindly show how to adopt this for `write`?

Comment: @BaRud I have added a skeleton function and example call to the end of the answer